# How to pass additional parameters to Jquery Datatable Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a Jquery Datatable with server side actions..Here I need a date between search of a datetime column..I would like to pass the *FromDate* and *ToDate* input field values to the jquery datatable ajax call method..

Here What i have done till now:

**Input fields:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>From Date: <input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" value=""></td>
               <td>To Date: <input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate"></td>
           </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery Datatable Code:**

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                // Setup - add a text input to each header cell

                $('#myTable thead tr:eq(0) th:not(:last)').each(function () {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
                });

                var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    //"scrollY": "300px",
                    "scrollX": true,
                    "fixedColumns": {
                        leftColumns: 1,
                        rightColumns: 1
                    },
                    "AutoWidth": false,
                    "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "aLengthMenu": [[2, 5, 6, -1], [2, 5, 6, "All"]],
                    "iDisplayLength": 2,


                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Payment/DueCollectioListLoad",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype": "json",

                      //this is what i have done to pass the input fields values

                        "data": { fromDate: $("#fromDate").val(), toDate: $("#toDate").val()}
                    },
                    "columns": [

                        //here is other column fields

                    ]
                });

                //// Apply the search

                $(table.table().container()).on('focusout', 'thead input', function () {
                    table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                });

                $('#maxValue').on('focusout', function () {
                    table.draw();
                });


            });


        </script>
```

**Here is Controller Action method:**

```
public ActionResult DueCollectioListLoad(string fromDate, string toDate)
{
     //Here is necessary code
}
```

**Everything is doing fine but Unfortunately *fromDate* and *toDate* parameter values are getting always null..any help please!**

Comment: cant find `minValue` and `maxValue` in your html. Maybe it should have been `"data": { fromValue: $("#fromDate").val(), toValue : $("#toDate").val(}`

Comment: Check it now please!! Forgot to modify all places correctly..Yes! you are correct but it does not work as well..Parameter values getting always null.

Comment: before your `var table` try run `console.log("date is : " + $("#fromDate").val())` and tell me if you get the correct value

Comment: Sorry! Its getting the value properly...as "date is : 25"

Comment: Try https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27216/how-to-get-the-parameters-on-mvc-controller-send-by-ajax-serverside-datatable-1-10

Comment: i wrote a post on this recently that will help i think see : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170086/Grid-with-Server-Side-Advanced-Search-using-JQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataTable` param object should be as follows:

```
public class DataTableParams
{
    public int Draw { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public ColumnRequestItem[] Columns { get; set; }
    public OrderRequestItem[] Order { get; set; }
    public SearchRequestItem Search { get; set; }

    // here are the two additional properties

    public string FromDate { get; set; } 
    public string ToDate { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnRequestItem
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Searchable { get; set; }
    public bool Orderable { get; set; }
    public SearchRequestItem Search { get; set; }
}

public class OrderRequestItem
{
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}

public class SearchRequestItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Regex { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the datatable `ajax`:

```
"ajax":{
     ................
     'contentType': 'application/json',
     'data': function(d) {
       d.FromDate = $("#fromDate").val(),
       d.ToDate = $("#toDate").val()

       return JSON.stringify(d);
    }
    ............
},
```

Now in the controller method:

```
public ActionResult DueCollectioListLoad([FromBody] DataTableParams dataTableParams)
{
     //Here is necessary code
}
```